# Dynamically creating X number of class objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dynamic

The background...

Lets say I have a class called cars.  We are just going to store the car name and an ID. 
Lets also say I have an admin page based on an admin class that I set the total number of cars I want to create in an int called totalCars

The question:
How do I dynamically create cars as fields that can be accessed from anywhere in the code, while at the same time creating a total number of cars based on the number in totalCars?

example code:

```
      Cars car1 = new Cars();
      int totalCars;
      //Somehow I want to create cars objects/fields based on the 
      //number in the totalCars int
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          car1.Name = "Chevy";
          car1.ID = 1;

      }

      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         TextBox1.Text = car1.Name.ToString();
         //this is just a sample action.
      }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just have a `List<Car>`? If the code which generates the fields is dynamic, how can the rest of the code expect those fields to be there?

Comment: Why you want to create such list that you wanted to access in different pages? You need to push that list into Session or Application scope :(

Comment: The reason I approached the problem this way is that I may have 5000 car objects.
Not every user should see every car later. 
I was concerned that the List<car> would be too large and slow down the system. / use to much memory.

Comment: If you're to that point then you should have a database; you shouldn't be persisting that type of information in memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should de the trick:

```
int CarCount = 100;
Car[] Cars = Enumerable
            .Range(0, CarCount)
            .Select(i => new Car { Id = i, Name = "Chevy " + i })
            .ToArray();
```

Regards GJ

**Edit**

If you just want to know how you would do such a thing (which you shouldn't), try this:

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {

    partial class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Generate();
        }

        static void Generate() {

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Program_Generated.cs");
            sw.WriteLine("using ConsoleApplication3;");
            sw.WriteLine("partial class Program {");

            string template = "\tCar car# = new Car() { Id = #, Name = \"Car #\" };";
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                sw.WriteLine(template.Replace("#", i.ToString()));
            }

            sw.WriteLine("}");
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }    

    class Car {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note the keyword `partial class`, this mean that you can have a class that spans multiple source files. Now you can code one by hand, and generate the other.

If you run this code it will generate this code:

```
using ConsoleApplication3;
partial class Program {
    Car car1 = new Car() { Id = 1, Name = "Car 1" };
    Car car2 = new Car() { Id = 2, Name = "Car 2" };
    ...
    Car car99 = new Car() { Id = 99, Name = "Car 99" };
    Car car100 = new Car() { Id = 100, Name = "Car 100" };
}
```

You can the add this code file to your solution (right click project.. add existing..) and compile it. Now you can use these variables car1 .. car100.

Comment: ok, the list is most likely the best solution.  As well as adding a database to the application.  This has not answered the ultimate question though.  The question was related to using the cars class to dynamically create X number of cars.

Comment: Example...  LEts say I have a int totalCars = 100.  Then I want to create Cars car1 = new Cars(); Cars car2 = new Cars(); .............   Cars car100 = new Cars();  Part of this question is related to learning, not just best practice.

Comment: WHat you're asking for is Code Generation, but I'm pretty sure you're asking the wrong question. What is it you want to do that way? It would be hell to program against.

Comment: added example just for academic purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List<Cars>`:

```
  List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();
  int totalCars;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      cars = new List<Cars>();
      for(int i=0; i<totalCars; i++)
      {  
           cars.Add(
              new Cars()
                {
                  Name = "Car #" + i;
                  ID = i;
                }
              );
      }          
  }
```